# How to select in css 1st 4th 5th or 2nd 3rd 6th element

Tags: css

How to use css nth child selector properly?

I have 6 divs and i need to select 1st 4th and 5th element, I can get 1st and 4th but cannot get the 5th element.

That's what i tried at the moment:

```
 .partners-logo:nth-child(3n+1) {
     background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: You need to create two selectors IMHO

Comment: the pattern of the duplicate isn't the same but the explanation given in the accepted answer will help find any kind of pattern

Answer (score 0):

i don't think was a different way.

```css
div:nth-child(1),
div:nth-child(4),
div:nth-child(5){
  color:red;
}

div:nth-child(2),
div:nth-child(3),
div:nth-child(6){
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>te</div>
<div>te</div>
<div>te</div>
<div>te</div>
<div>te</div>
<div>te</div>
```

Comment: This is for static pages, what if you add 6 more elements?

Comment: @SmolskisDominykas Well, if you write _"I have 6 divs ..."_, you'll get an answer covering just that.

Answer (score 0):

cannot select these three numbers at the same time...

***Method -1***

```
.partners-logo:nth-child(1),
.partners-logo:nth-child(4),
.partners-logo:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.partners-logo:nth-child(2),
.partners-logo:nth-child(3),
.partners-logo:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7
}
```

***Method - 2*** You can use `:nth-child(-4n+6)` for 2-6 and `:nth-child(-3n+4)` for 1-4...

```
.partners-logo:nth-child(-3n+4),
.partners-logo:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.partners-logo:nth-child(-4n+6),
.partners-logo:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7
}
```